# OpenCV stitcher routine in C , how to get pixel transform?

Tags: c++, opencv

So, I managed to implement panoramic stitching in C++ using opencv's stitcher routine.

When the stitching is complete, the output shows the initial intrinsic parameters, and the camera parameters for each stitch as a 3x3 matrix.

What do these parameters mean?

I want to find out the pixel mapping from each individual image to the resultant panorama. What are the pixels offset by. This is probably a 2d vector, because the pixels are translated to the left or the right, and then translated up or down.

How do I get this data for each pixel in the output panorama?

Answer (score 2):

3x3 matrix is just a representation of the 2d affine transformation (scaling + rotation + translation).

To convert (x1, y1) on one image to (x2, y2) on another image having the stitching matrix M you just do the

```
 (x1, y1, 1) = M * (x2, y2, 1)
```

where `*` is the usual matrix-by-vector multiplication.

See here [(Wiki, Affine transform)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transform) about such matrices and homogeneous (triple) coordinates.

Comment: What you're talking about is a Homography matrix, correct? The matrix returned from the stitching is not a Homography matrix, but a camera matrix.